# Different permissions per log file when using rsyslog

Tags: permissions, log-files, rsyslog

Is it feasible to define different permissions per log file, using rsyslog?

$FileCreateMode applies to all, but I want different permissions for a specific file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [official documentation on *Configuration*,](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/omfile.html)

> FileCreateMode may be specified multiple times. If so, it specifies the creation mode for all selector lines that follow until the next $FileCreateMode directive. Order of lines is vitally important.